# How to show that a (metric) space having a countable dense subset is a topological property?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have to show that a (metric) space having a countable dense subset is a topological property.

Given that A property P of a space is said to be a topological property if home-omorphic spaces share the same properties.

I think if i can show that two seperable spaces are homeomorphic then i can say that this is a topological property. I need help to understand this and how to show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must show this property is preserved by homeomorphisms, i.e. if $X$ has this property and $f: X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $Y$ has this property.

Given a countable dense subset $D$ of $X$, what can you tell about $f(D)$?

By the way, it is not true that two separable spaces are homeomorphic. A finite space and a countable infinite space are both trivially separable but there cannot be a bijection between these two.

Comment: If f is continuous and onto then f(D) is dense in Y. Since f is a homeomorphism then both this conditions hold so f(D) is dense in Y. So this argument is enough?

Comment: Yes, but you need to justify that $f(D)$ is a dense countable subset of $Y$.

Comment: I was not saying that two seperable spaces are homeomorphic. I was saying if i can find a homeomorphism between two seperable spaces then my claim will hold. But thank you.

Comment: Alright! I'm sure you understand what's going on! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a separable space which is homeomorphic to $Y$ via $f: X \to Y$. Then there exists a subset $A \subset X$ such that $\overline{A} = X$. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism and in particular surjective, $f(A) \subset Y$ is countable. All it remains to show is that $\overline{f(A)} = Y$. Indeed, given any open set $O \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(O) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ (since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$) because $A$ is dense in $X$, therefore $$f(A \cap f^{-1}(O)) = f(A) \cap f(f^{-1}(O))) = f(A) \cap O \neq \emptyset$$

as desired. Since homeomorphisms form an equivalence relation, we conclude that two homeomorphic topological spaces are either both separable or both non separable.